# Storing WIFI signal strength as a variable

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I need to store the wifi signal strength as a variable. I know you can use "netsh wlan show networks mode=bssid," but I need to store only the signal strength portion. Is there any way to store this portion as a variable for further consulting in batch? If you cannot do so in batch with ease, then is there a way to do so in powershell?

Comment: You've neglected to include a `?` with your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help man... I was indirectly asking a question. May someone tell me how to store the WiFi signal as a variable?

Comment: Are you asking how to parse text (output of the command) in a batch file? Simple findstr (or grep) won't help because there may be several SSIDs, you need to specify certain SSID. Or do you want to extract all signals as an array? Another option is using AWK to parse. If you don't have awk, loop thru the text using  variant of *for* command (see help for that) and parse each line. Best of all, use powershell instead of cmd.

Comment: I want it from a specific SSID, if it is possible. However, if it isn't I will do it using the for command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this, which allows you to specify a certain SSID, but shows all when input is left blank:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "TestSSID="
set /p "TestSSID=SSID: "
echo Getting signal strengths . . .
for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=: " %%a in ('netsh wlan show networks mode^=bssid') do (
    if "%%a"=="SSID" set "SSID=%%c"
    if "%%a"=="Signal" (
        set "Signal=%%b"
        if "!TestSSID!"=="" echo !SSID!: !Signal!
        if "!TestSSID!"=="!SSID!" echo !SSID!: !Signal!
        )
    )
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

`netsh` has no modifier to get infos from a specific SSID. But getting info for a specific interface is possible:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('netsh wlan show networks interface^="Wireless Network Connection" mode ^= bssid ^|find "Signal"') do echo %%i
```